# Javascript - Open keyboard with capslock(shift) on when clicking on input

Tags: javascript, input, keyboard

I want the shift button on a mobile keyboard to be automatically pressed when the user has clicked on an input, I need this because I want the keyboard to display capital letters when the input is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="test1" autocapitalize="characters"/>
```

Just add the attribute autocapitalize, here is the documentation for iOS and Android:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-autocapitalize

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/autocapitalize